# Python os.walk and os.path on mounted directory in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, mount, cifs

I have mounted a CIFS share in Linux on CentOS and I am trying to work with the contents using Python 2.7.

This is what I did in Linux:

1. I first created the path `/mnt/cifs` using `mkdir -p /mnt/cifs`.
2. Next, I mounted the cifs share to `/mnt/cifs`. If I run this command at the Linux terminal:

   `ls /mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup`

   then I see the contents of the `Dir_Backup` directory listed correctly. So, this confirms that the mount has worked correctly.

Next, I need to use Python for the rest of the operations. Here is what I am trying to do with Python:

```
mypath = '/mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup'

mylist = []
ss = []
fullpath = []

for path, _s, _f in os.walk(mypath):
    for myname in _f:
        mylist.append(myname)
        fullp = os.path.join(path,myname)
        fullpath.append(fullp)
        ss.append(_s)
        print fullp,myname
```

I placed this code in a python file and ran it with `python backup_directory.py`.

However, the code is just hanging: it does not do anything (no statement is printed to screen like I instructed it to) and it does not return the command prompt.

Is there a way to work with `os.walk()` and `os.path.join()` specifically on on mounted directories in Linux?

**Correction 1:**

Fixed variable inside loop - should have been `path` not `mypath`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I fixed the error. It should be `/mnt/cifs`.

Comment: have you tried things like `os.listdir('/mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup')`, `os.path.isdir('/mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup')` ? have you tried upgrading to python 3.5?

Comment: When I tried `os.listdir('/mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup')`, I got a message `Could not find the path /mnt/cifs/Dir_Backup`. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade to Python 3.5. Is this a known problem with Python 2.7?

Comment: no, but I know that they fixed a lot of stuff in directory scanning in 3.5, so it would have more chances to work. Can you `os.listdir` directories _inside_ your dir_backup directory? if so I could propose a workaround.

Comment: Are you running `ls` command and your Python script from the same user? I'm asking because in the Linux only root user can create a folder in the `/mnt` folder. And in case of mounting cifs folder, there may be an issue there. Can you provide your output for the `mount` command with the mounted `cifs` partition?

Also, it looks like you append files to the `mypath` variable, not `path`. Are you sure it is OK there? (Path becomes invalid in this case).

Comment: @wanderlust: (a) Sorry for the second mistake - fixed it - as you said it should be `path` inside the loop. (b) the cifs is mounted with the usual `mount -t cifs .... /mnt/cifs` - I don't usually get any output from the mount cifs command. I didn't get any output this time either. I can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to manually work with the files without any problems or ls to list the contents as normal. @Jean-FrançoisFabre: unfortunately, I get the same error when I try to use `listdir` on the sub-directories.

Comment: @WR can you run the following commands in the terminal: (a) `whoami` (b) `mount`; I assume both commands should be run in the same window and as the same user you run your script.